# What is the significance of `\` and `/` in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am using Windows 10. Right now, I am using Visual Studio 2016 IDE for my Python and OpenCV development. For example, when I want to read an image with this code:

```
image = cv2.imread('C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I cannot read the image. Instead, I have to write it like this for the path of the image:

```
image = cv2.imread('C:\Users\MyName\Desktop/test.jpg')
```

What is this? I've read about the history of why `\` is being used in Windows but in my situation right now, when do I know when to use `backslash` or `forward slash`?

Comment: ``\`` is the start of an *escape sequence*. `\t` for example is a tab character, not a backslash and a `t`.

Comment: `I've read about the history of why \ is being used in Windows.`

Can you share the link, I would like to read about it.

Comment: You can always use forward slashes in Windows filenames, Windows doesn't actually *care*.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/

Comment: @MartijnPieters: NO.  You can *sometimes* use forward slashes in Windows filenames.  *It doesn't always work.*

Comment: @HarryJohnston: as far as Python's interactions with Windows APIs is concerned, you can. Python doesn't care that the *Run* command doesn't accept such paths, for example.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: but I do concede my comment was imprecise in that I failed to constrain it to Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I should think there are a few edge cases, such as shelling out to a command with a file argument.  But yes, I'd misinterpreted it as a more blanket statement than intended. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, slash can only be used in DOS paths. You have to use backslash with extended paths that use the ``\\?\`` prefix, because this prefix bypasses the path normalization usually applied in the NT runtime library that converts a DOS path to an NT path. You also have to use backslash to access `Global` named kernel objects (e.g. `Global\SomeGlobalEvent`) instead of those in the local `\Sessions\[Session Number]\BaseNamedObjects`. The session `Global` is an object link to the root `\BaseNamedObjects`. In both cases it's because only backslash is a path separator in the native NT API.

Comment: @eryksun: which is why we love the stratified layers of the Windows API *so much*. *cough*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your answer pretty much explained everything. Thanks!